# ember data in standalone cli node.js app

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This might be sort of a dumb question, but is it possible/advisable to use ember data without ember for a command line node.js app I'm writing?   I already have a set of Ember Data models in my frontend project that I'd love to reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ember-data* uses features of the *Ember* itself, or, more precise, it is based on ember and will be merged into it in some point at future, thus you will have to include the ember library and its dependencies(handlebars) for ember-data to work, but after that you can only use parts that you need, like models.

Comment: Bummer, any good alternatives like Ember Data for Node? I'm a real a fan of Ember Data, especially it's computer properties support.